# How to Automate QR Codes in Excel 2016

Tags: excel, qr-code, google-apis-explorer

I need to generate a whole sheet of QR codes, (eventually about 1000), i am trying to automate the generation in Excel 2016, i currently have a sheet set up and have a URL to the generater using Google Apis, I just change the ID number in the url for it to take me to make the next code and take me to the correct place. I dont want to have to manually go and get the code and copy it into my document for each one.

Does anyone have any ideas that may help me out, i have set up the first 10 and this can be seen on the screenshot attached.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ti3Ly.jpg)

Thanks

Comment: Can you add that google API link you use in your question to create the QR codes? (that would help us help you).

Answer (score 1):

You can use this VBA code to your Excel file,then you have to make a selection for the cells that you want to create QR Codes for them, then run the code "InsertQR" by (Alt+F8)
The VBA code will create QR codes for each selected cell as PNG file.
Note: You must be connected to the Internet

```
Sub InsertQR()
    Dim xHttp: Set xHttp = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    Dim bStrm: Set bStrm = CreateObject("Adodb.Stream")
    Dim size: size = 500 'dalam Pixels
    Dim QR, Name, val
    Dim Invalid: Invalid = "\/:*?" & """" & "<>|"
    For Each val In Selection
        Name = val.Value
        For intChar = 1 To Len(Name)
            If InStr(Invalid, LCase(Mid(Name, intChar, 1))) > 0 Then
                MsgBox "The file: " & vbCrLf & """" & Name & """" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & " is invalid!"
                Exit Sub
            End If
        Next
        QR = "http://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=" & size & "x" & size & "&cht=qr&chl=" & Name
        xHttp.Open "GET", QR, False
        xHttp.Send
        With bStrm
            .Type = 1 '//binary
            .Open
            .write xHttp.responseBody
            .savetofile ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & Name & ".png", 2 '//overwrite
            .Close
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the closest thing I could find with what you are trying to do.

https://sites.google.com/site/e90e50fx/home/generate-qrcode-with-excel

It's generate a QR code image but I can't get it to do it for multiple cell values.